# Detected BIOS data in system (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, bios, chipset

How detected name of modern chipsets in system (Delphi)

Answer (score 8):

WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) have routines to detect computer hardware.

The best Delphi package for WMI is [wmi-delphi-code-creator](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/).

Look for documentation for the calls Win32_BaseBoard and Win32_MotherboardDevice.

They won't give you the chipset name though.

A scan through the Win32_PnPEntity class looking for vendor/device ID and matching them with the correct chipset is probably the best way. Not an easy task.

Some more info [chipset-detection-in-delphi](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/94173-chipset-detection-in-delphi/)

Edit : Credits to the author of the package, [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz)

Answer (score 8):

As LU RD has pointed out, WMI is the way to go. Check out [Rodrigo Ruz WMI code generator](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/object-pascal-wmi-class-generator/), it make access really easy.

Comment: @RRUZ: Thank you for correcting my link to the code generator.